# Must a "target creature" be on the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an ability says "target creature," does the creature have to be on the battlefield? I think I found a loophole that depends on the answer.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what was the possible loophole you found?

Comment: Your question could be simplified to *"What is a creature?"* Once that has been established, it's clear what *"target creature"* means.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it does.  The rules say:

> 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

i.e., "creature" can only mean a creature permanent on the battlefield.

Comment: I'd just like to add that it is a default e.g. card may say "**target creature** card in your graveyard" in which case, it has to target a creature in the grave. Rule 109.2 does say this but I don't think it has been made clear

Comment: @LukeDrew: in that case, it says creature **card**.

Comment: I liked the old "Enchant dead creature" of animate dead. The new wording is so convoluted!

Comment: @Luke Drew, Since the word "card" is included, 109.2 doesn't apply. "Creature" acts as an adjective modifying "card" in that sentence. "target creature card" means "target card (that is a creature)", not "target creature (that is a card)".

Comment: Maybe I wasn't too clear, I was trying to say that "target creature" is also appears in "**target creature** _card_ in your graveyard" which is why I had "target creature" in bold. I think in the end, I was trying to point out maybe you should make a point that if it is followed by one of the words in 109.2, then you can't target something on the battlefield. If you think that rule 109.2 makes that clear without explaining it, then feel free to ignore me. I'm sorry if this still makes no sense since I'm not the best at explaining things :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when targeting a permanent, creature, artifact, enchantment, planeswalker or land, it must be on the battlefield. When targeting specifies targeting a spell, it must be on the stack (like with [counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bcounterspell%5d)). There are exceptions to this, but they all specify how they work, for example:

- [Animate Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnimate%20Dead%5d) specifies it enchants a "creature card in a graveyard".
- [Zombify](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZombify%5d) uses the words "target creature from your graveyard" by saying it's coming from the graveyard, that's the only place it can be when you target it.
- [Runic Repetion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRunic%20Repetion%5d) specifies it returns a card from exile, defining the zone where the card had to be to be targeted.

Comment: The first sentence is a bit confusing, because a permanent that isn't on the battlefield isn't a thing that exists in the game; a permanent is always on the battlefield. It also doesn't really address the question; because the asker didn't know if "target creature" meant that the target had to be a permanent.

Comment: @GendoIkari better?

Comment: In my opinion, calling those examples "exceptions" is less clear than just describing or quoting the actual rule for how this works, as the other answer does.

Comment: Right, as Rainbolt's comment on the question says, the issue here is not knowing what the game means when it says "creature". It's not that the creature must be on the battlefield unless stated otherwise.. it's that "creature" by definition can only exist on the battlefield; outside of the battlefield it has a different name ("creature card").